# rails accessing hashes with variables

Tags: ruby, key-value, hash

```
v = { "foo"=>"bar"}  
v["foo"] // bar
```

Say,

```
k = {:bar => 1}
>k[:bar] // 1
```

But,

```
k[v["foo"]] // nil
```

how to access `key ==> value ( k[ key ] = value )` from hashes using a variable, say `v["foo"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to run `to_sym` on the result of `v["foo"]` in order to the the value in `k`:

```
1.9.3p484 :007 > v = { "foo"=>"bar"}  
 => {"foo"=>"bar"} 
1.9.3p484 :008 > k = {:bar => 1}
 => {:bar=>1} 
1.9.3p484 :009 > k[v["foo"].to_sym]
 => 1
```

Comment: Thanks. Couldnt find any doc's relating to this. Was trying with symbolize_keys, dint work

Comment: You bet.  Let me know if you have any other questions, or hit the checkmark if you want to close the question.